# Angular 2: Apply remote validation errors to form

Tags: forms, validation, angular

When submitting a form to my backend, I might get a response with http code 400  indicating that validation has failed.

My backend responds with for example:

```js
{  
  "status":"fail",
  "data":{  
    "email":[  
      "Email address already in use"
    ]
  }
}
```

I would like to invalidate the email field and set the error message, based on the response.

What I've tried is this:

```js
if (err && err.status === 400) {
    const response = err.json();
    Object.keys(response.data).forEach(key => {
        const messages = response.data[key];
        this.registerForm.get(key).setErrors({
            remote: messages[0] // Set just the first message
        }, true);
    });
}
```

This seems to work in part, the problem is that my controls does not get invalid status unless I focus the control by clicking the input.

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug? All my Googling seems to confirm that I'm doing it correctly.

Any input appr

Answer (score 0):

You can re-implement the register form adapting the reactive form style, where you can perform custom validation of form inputs and do asynchronous validation by returning promises to form to update on resolving the promise.
You may check in Angular 2 documentation for implementing reactive form validation : [Reactive Form Validation - Angular 2](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html#!#reactive)